# Django error message in class based view

Tags: django, python-3.x

Can I change the error message from the model for a class-based view? the following is not working, it always gives the default message from Django.

Model:

```
class Child(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, error_messages={ 'blank': 'cannot be blank or null', 'null': 'cannot be blank or null',})
```

view:

```
class ChildCreate(CreateView):
  model = Child
  fields = '__all__'
  success_url = reverse_lazy('children-list')
```

Comment: you have to create a ModelForm in forms.py and add that form in your view form_class=<your_form_class_name> add the error_message attribute in forms it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#considerations-regarding-model-errormessages):

> Error messages defined at the form field level or at the form Meta
>   level always take precedence over the error messages defined at the
>   model field level.

So you can create model form and add `required` error message there:

```
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    use_required_attribute = False

    class Meta:
        model = models.Child
        fields = '__all__'
        error_messages = {'name': {'required': 'cannot be blank or null'}} 

class ChildCreate(CreateView):
    model = Child
    form_class = forms.ChildForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('children-list')
```

Comment: still shows me this pop message: Please fill out this field.

Comment: @Yousef to disable popup use `use_required_attribute = False` form's attribute. See update.